# 3 fingers swipe change workspace in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch

I just bought an Dell XPS 13 and for my work I have a Macbook.

I want to use the touchpad for changing workspaces. I have found some questions but all the answers provided does not work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there someone that got the 3 finger swipe working for switching workspaces?

Comment: @Daniel Why do you claim that obsolete 14.10 and non-LTS 15.04 are more stable that 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Wrong button @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 15.04 and I got the three finger swipe working with **xSwipe**. I did it by following this tutorial:

**Ubuntu 13.10, Mint 16, and Up**

First download the following dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libevdev-dev autoconf automake libmtdev-dev xorg-dev xutils-dev libtool
```

Now, we need to remove the old driver so the new one will overwrite it.

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then, clone the source and build the new driver!

```
git clone https://github.com/felipejfc/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.git
cd xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
./autogen.sh
./configure --exec_prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

When this completes, reboot and make sure your pointer works.

**Setting up xSwipe**

First install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-guitest-perl
```

Then enable SHMConfig to allow for handling of the gestures.

```
mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Fill the file with the following, and save it!

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "evdev touchpad catchall" 
Driver "synaptics" 
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" 
MatchIsTouchpad "on" 
Option "Protocol" "event"
Option "SHMConfig" "on"
EndSection
```

Now clone xSwipe to a location of your choosing.

```
git clone https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe.git
```

And change the eventkey.cfg file to your liking. EDIT: It seems in both 13.10 and 14.04 versions of Ubuntu (and any version of Cinnamon), the keys set in the "other" category are the ones that are signaled on key swipes. Ignore the ubuntu and gnome sections for unity and cinnnamon.

```
cd xSwipe/
nano eventkey.cfg
```

Now test by running:

```
perl xSwipe.pl
```

Try to swipe with different gestrues and check the terminal to see if they are working. If they are, you may now add the script to your start up programs depending on your environment. After it is added, reboot and you should have working multitouch gestures!

Update: This seems to take about an hour out of my battery life. To get around this, I change the sensitivity with the parameter -m 30.

```
perl xSwipe.pl -m 30
```

All credits go to Matthew Iannucci, find this tutorial and comments here: [Whole tutorial](http://blog.mpiannucci.com/view/multitouchgesture)

**If this does not work for you, you can try the tutorial of iberianpig, who made xSwipe.** -> [Tutorial](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe)

If you want to configure the gestures look here: -> https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe/wiki/Customize-eventKey.cfg

Here is my eventKey.cfg already configured for the 3 finger workspace swipe: http://pastebin.com/f1E1L26V

Comment: Unfortunately the new `xserver-xorg` from felipejfc does not seem to work properly for me.   `xserver-xorg` is broken after a reboot.